# Model theoretic semantics of statement identifiers in RDF 1.1 Semantics

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, semantics, rdfs

I want to formailze the semantics of adding statement identifiers to RDF. The purpose of these identifiers is to denote statements and be used to reify those statement so that one can make assertions about them, add attributes to them etc. (1). They shall be:

- freshly minted IRIs (2)
- unique per statement (3)
- usable as subjects and/or objects of further statements.

This seems reasonably clear to me but it would be useful to also formally define the model theoretic semantics of these statement identifiers. The RDF 1.1 Semantics document [1] defines a simple interpretation as follows:

```
     1. A non-empty set IR of resources, called the domain or universe of I.
     2. A set IP, called the set of properties of I.
     3. A mapping IEXT from IP into the powerset of IR x IR 
        i.e. the set of sets of pairs < x, y > with x and y in IR . 
     4. A mapping IS from IRIs into (IR union IP)
     5. A partial mapping IL from literals into IR
```

The **first approach** I came up with is to modify this definition by
- adding ID':

```
    6'. A set ID', called the set of statement identifiers of I.
```

- modifying IS to IS':

```
    4'. A mapping IS' from IRIs into (IR union IP union ID')
```

- and modifying IEXT to IEXT’:

```
    3'. A mapping IEXT' from IP into the powerset of 
        (IR union ID') x (IR union ID') x ID'
        i.e. the set of sets of triples <x,y,id> 
        with x and y in (IR union ID') and id in ID'.
```

I'm not sure however if this works as intended. It troubles me particularily that IR, the domain or universe of I as defined in 1. above, is disjoint from ID'. It has to be possible to use statement identifiers as subjects or objects in other statements (that's the whole point of this endeavour). OTOH it also has to be ensured that these identifiers are not taken from the existing set of IRIs but are freshly minted.

A **second approach** could be to
- change the set ID' to a mapping ID":

```
    6". A mapping ID" from an IRI p of IP and a pair <x,y> with x and y in IR
        to an IRI id, adding id to IR.
```

- and modify IEXT to IEXT", calling ID" for every pair:

```
    3". A mapping IEXT" from IP into the powerset of IR x IR x ID"
        i.e. the set of sets of triples <x,y,id> with x and y in IR 
        and id minted by ID".
```

Here I first define a function ID" to mint identifiers for a given property p and a pair  from p's extension. Then I call that function for each mapping IEXT" from p in IP to a pair  in its extension. ID" returns an id to IEXT" for that partcular mapping and also adds the id to IR so that it can be used in further  pairs.
I'm quite unsure though if this is a legitimate way to define a formal semantics. Probably the idea of "calling" a mapping as a function is already unappropriate.

(1) The idea is not new: it has been implemented in RDF stores internally, it has been called "Named Triples" etc. However I'm not aware of any formal, model theoretic specification of its semantics. I am aware of RDF's standard reification mechanism and other approaches to reification in RDF. I don't want to discuss the merits and shortcomings of any of these approaches here. I'm mentioning them only to provide some context to this question. Here I only want to discuss how to correctly formalize this specific approach. I believe this is a genuinely technical question and it would be better discussed here, with the fine instruments that Stackoverflow provides, than on a mailing list.
(2) maybe through a hash function but I would like to leave that open for now.
(3) Questions of how to ensure global uniqueness of statement identifiers or how to handle merges of graphs with different identifiers for the statement or vice versa shall be ignored here for the sake of simplicity of the example.

[1] http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.3399 ?

Comment: While the question is very interesting, it is not appropriate for Stack Overflow because there is no uncontroversial answer. This problem has been thoroughly researched since RDF semantics was first formalised in the early 2000s, and no one could devise a proposal that estabilishes a consensus. Perhaps you should rather open a discussion on the Semantic Web mailing list.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann I'm not asking for a discussion on what is the most appropriate approach to reification in RDF which is the controvery you refer to. I'm asking how to formalize the specific approach outlined above in a model theoretic semantics. That is a very technical question (and II'm not aware of any formalization of a similar approach).

Comment: tom lurge, what you are asking is a technical question that does not have a unique possible answer. You even have two options already in your question. There are other possibilities, none of which make a consensus at all. Moreover, a question about model theory is not really on topic for Stack Overflow anyway, as far as I understand. So, no, this is not a question appropriate to SO.

Comment: Technical questions often have more than one possible answer. If someone told me that both of my proposed solutions work that would be fine by me. But I'll take the question over to the semantic web mailinglist as nobody else here seems to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

After some more thinking and reading I came to the conclusion that probably the RDF 1.1 Semantics definition of a simple interpretation doesn't need any modification. After all I'm defining new IRIs per statement. Those IRIs shall be unique and they shall be used as subjects or objects in other statements. That's all covered by the standard RDF model theory. RDF Abstract Syntax of course needs to be amended but that's another story.